# getting Data on specifique orders

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, orm

i have table of users and every user has a role and a ParentID
i want to get an array on specifique order based on role and ParentID,

the objectif of getting a specifique order is to create a tree view to visualisate all the users in a tree HTML view arborecence using vueJS

for exemple this is list of users :

```
     [
        {'id' : 1, 'name' : 'user 1', 'role_id' : 1 , 'parentId' : 1},
        {'id' : 2, 'name' : 'user 2', 'role_id' : 1 , 'parentId' : 2},
        {'id' : 3, 'name' : 'user 3', 'role_id' : 2 , 'parentId' : 1},
        {'id' : 4, 'name' : 'user 4', 'role_id' : 2 , 'parentId' : 1},
        {'id' : 5, 'name' : 'user 5', 'role_id' : 2 , 'parentId' : 2},
        {'id' : 6, 'name' : 'user 6', 'role_id' : 2 , 'parentId' : 2},
        {'id' : 7, 'name' : 'user 7', 'role_id' : 3 , 'parentId' : 3},
        {'id' : 8, 'name' : 'user 8', 'role_id' : 3 , 'parentId' : 3},
        {'id' : 9, 'name' : 'user 9', 'role_id' : 3 , 'parentId' : 5},
        {'id' : 10, 'name' : 'user 10', 'role_id' : 3 , 'parentId' : 6},
     ]
```

and this is how i want to get the array :

```
$users : [
        {
            'id':1,
            'name' : 'user 1',
            'role_id' : 1,
            'N1' : [
                {
                    'id' : 3,
                    'name' : 'user 3',
                    'role_id' : 2,
                    'N2' : [
                        {
                            'id':7,
                            'name' : 'user 7',
                            'role_id' : 3,
                            'N3' : []
                        },
                        {
                            'id':8,
                            'name' : 'user 8',
                            'role_id' : 3,
                            'N3' : []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'id' : 4,
                    'name' : 'user 4',
                    'role_id' : 2,
                    'N2' : []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'id':2,
            'name' : 'user 2',
            'role_id' : 1,
            'N1' : [
                {
                    'id' : 5,
                    'name' : 'user 5',
                    'role_id' : 2,
                    'N2' : [
                        {
                            'id' : 9,
                            'name' : 'user 9',
                            'role_id' : 3,
                            'N3' : []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    'id' : 6,
                    'name' : 'user 6',
                    'role_id' : 2,
                    'N2' : [
                        {
                            'id' : 10,
                            'name' : 'user 10',
                            'role_id' : 3,
                            'N3' : []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

and this is my backend function to get the result i want (not working correctly)

```
public function getMyTeamForTreeView(){
        $parentId = Auth::user()->user_parent_id;
        $userAuth = Auth::user()->id;
        $userAuthRoleId = Auth::user()->role_id;
        $userAuthAgenceId = Auth::user()->agency_id;

        $roles = Role::where('agence_id',0)->orWhere('agence_id',$userAuthAgenceId)->get();
        
        // dd($roles[1]->id);

        if($userAuthRoleId == 1){
            $admins = User::select('id','user_fname','user_lname')->where('agency_id',$userAuthAgenceId)->where('role_id',1)->get();

            
                foreach($admins as $admin){
                    $numberOfRoles = count($roles);
                    $i = 1;
                    $j = 0;
                    
                    while($numberOfRoles >= 1){

                        // echo $roles[$i]->id;

                        $admin['N'.$i] = User::select('id','user_fname','user_lname')->where('role_id',$roles[$i]->id)->where('agency_id',$userAuthAgenceId)->get();
                        // dd($admin['N1']);
                        foreach($admin['N'.$i] as $user){
                            $myArray = User::select('id','user_fname','user_lname')->where('role_id',$j+1)->where('agency_id',$userAuthAgenceId)->where('user_parent_id',$user->id)->get();
                        }
                        $i++;
                        $j++;
                        $numberOfRoles--;
                    }
                }    
           
        }
        return response()->json($admins);
    }
```

and for the front-End part :

```
 <div class="tree">
                    <ul>
                      <li v-for="admin in tree">
                        <a href="#">@{{admin.name}}</a>
                        <ul>
                          <li v-for="N1 in admin.N1">
                            <a href="#">@{{ N1.name }}</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li v-for="N2 in admin.N1.N2">
                                    <a href="#">@{{ N2.name }}</a>
                                    <ul>
                                      <li v-for="N3 in admin.N1.N2.N3">
                                        <a href="#">@{{ N3.name }}</a>
                                      </li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

[image]

as you can see the vue part always gonna stop before one step and i want to implement the DFS algorithm for getting the specifique array  (Depth-first search)

thank you in advance